# Using NPM and Node.js without having admin access

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

So, recently our InfoSec group pushed out a new policy that removes local admin access for domain accounts.  That change hasn't affected our group too much, but recently I had one of the devs on my team send his laptop into the service desk to have a hardware issue looked into and, the service desk does what the service desk does, they reimaged the machine and removed his admin access.

Now, how they reimaged his machine is questionable as we have found some things that he could do before with admin access seemed to be locked out from him now only to find out that something didn't get installed correctly, like Postman or Nuget Package Manager.  However, he's still experiencing issues with NPM.  Whenever he tries to run NPM Install, NPM Audit, or NPM Update, he is prompted to enter in credentials with local admin access in order to run those commands, which means he has to reach out to tech to enter the local admin account password, which gets annoying and is time-consuming since now a dev is down waiting on a tech to enter a password.

So, my question is, can a user run node.js and NPM without having admin or power user access in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

A user can and should be able to run node.js and NPM without administrative privelages (unless you are installing a global package with the -g flag). If its installing npm packages normally, I think its the configuration of the command prompt set by your company. I would recommend contacting the support of your company to try to fix it.

Comment: do you happen to have any documentation on that?  I would like to read it and have it handy to share with our InfoSec and Service Desk teams